# Compare two images in xamarin.forms but ignore file size, dimension, orientation

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms. I want to compare two images. I want to compare captured image from camera with some static image but below condition should not be consider

1. Minor color changes should be ignored.
2. Some Dimension and image size should not affect
3. orientation should not consider

**Example: I have one photo of some company's logo like "LG". Now I am capture logo image from some mobile or any LG component device. These both images should be the match and ignore background color, orientation, dimension, size. Exact match not required.**

I want to implement this feature on both Android and IOS.

Is there any third party plugin available?

Is it possible in PCL or I have to do some platform specific code?

Comment: this is a fairly complex image analysis task.  You're not going to find any easy out-of-the-box solution for doing it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are absolutely right. Can i use openCV in xamarin forms? suppose I choose simple approach then what should be the better way from below links http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/prathore/image-comparison-using-C-Sharp/ and  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/krishnasarala/compare-two-images-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: I found some Microsoft cognitive services and Google APIs for image recognition. I haven't found any APIs to find image comparison. is there any API available which gives me how much similar images are?